# the columns are in disarray in asp:Repeater

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have this repeater I get this........... I want to have 4 columns and not 5 or 6 depending on the browser size........ thanks..

[image]

```
<style>
    .column
    {
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;
        background: yellow;
        float: left;
    }
</style>

//the repeater stretches as browser gets wider
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
    <ItemTemplate>
        <div class="column"> <%# Eval("FirstName") %> </div>
        <div class="column"> <%# Eval("LastName") %>  </div>
        <div class="column"><asp:LinkButton ID="Linkbutton1" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" /></div>
        <div class="column"><asp:LinkButton ID="Linkbutton2" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" /></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `table` (html) or `GridView` (ASP.NET control) for showing tabular data.

Or if you want to stick to your design put your `Repeater` in another `div` with fixed width of `800px` (sum of all 4 `divs`):

```
<style>
    .table
    {
        width: 800px;
    }
    .column
    {
        width: 200px;
        height: 50px;
        background: yellow;
        float: left;
    }
</style>

<div class="table">
  <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server" >
      <ItemTemplate>
          <div class="column"> <%# Eval("FirstName") %> </div>
          <div class="column"> <%# Eval("LastName") %>  </div>
          <div class="column"><asp:LinkButton ID="Linkbutton1" runat="server" Text="Edit" CommandName="Edit" /></div>
          <div class="column"><asp:LinkButton ID="Linkbutton2" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete" /></div>
      </ItemTemplate>
  </asp:Repeater>
</div>
```